# Finding <img> tags in HTML files in Powershell

Tags: html, parsing, powershell, collections

I want to create a simple code in Powershell that just checks what images are not used in a folder of HTMl files. So I want to open each HTML file locally (not via URI) and retrieve all the  tags. Doesn't sound too horrible.

I've done my research and it was going well, I came up with this code:

```
Foreach ($imageFile in $imageFiles){
    Foreach ($file in $HTMLFiles)
    {
        Write-Debug "Processing: $file"                    
        $html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
        $source = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
        $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source);       
        $nbImages = $html.Images.length        

        ForEach ($i in $html.Images){
            #$i.getTags("src")
        }          
    } 
}
```

Question 1: I'm working with HTML files that I (re)convert to HTML files to get access to useful methods. Is there a simple way?

Question 2 and **problem**: I just can't find a way to go through my collection of image tags. How do I do that?
I've checked how images my code finds in the sources, and it's correct. I just want to get the info from the collection itself.

Thank you for your help, I'm really stuck here!

Comment: u can use regex , r u interested?

Comment: @MohitBhasi **Do not use regex** for this. The approach OP is taking is the correct one. [Explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @MohitBhasi thanks but, as Arco said, there are a lot of methods available to avoid going into the regexp realm. I try to stay away from them as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell makes you think it's got equivalents for loops but doesn't.
A foreach does not do the same thing as |%{...}.

In my example, I have to replace my second foreach by how I retrieve my $HTMLFiles and redirect it to a %{}. That way, PS "knows" what's in the $htmlFiles variable.

**Conclusion**: 
Prefer pipes than foreach loops. Pipes lets PS keep track of what the result of an expression thanks to pipes. Foreach loops seem to prevent it from doing that.

**Conclusion 2 and more precision**:
Finally, i've found a way to do it with a foreach.
Instead of:

```
ForEach ($i in $html.Images){
  ...
}
```

Do:

```
$images= @($html.Images)
$images | ForEach {...}
```

Comment: Questions aren't place for answers. Why not put text here instead of posting it in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a regular expression like `/<img \w*>/g` for select all `<img>` tag

Comment: I refer you to the comment I left on the question.